# Finding the overall weighted centroid from other centroids

Tags: arcpy, centroids, population

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to find the overall weighted population centroid of a state, using the unweighted centroid from counties. These unweighted centroids already have a popualtion field ("totpop") in the attribute table. The tool runs, however, it outputs the overall centroid (in pink) in the incorrect spot. It falls on the last county's centroid.
[image]

```
import os
import arcpy
import math
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InPutPoints,["STATE_NAME","YCoord","XCoord","totpop", "NAME", "POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER","SHAPE@AREA","SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"]) as cursor:

    Total_X1 = 0
    Total_Y1 = 0
    TotalPop1 = 0
    cntyName1 = "cnty"
    stateName1 = "statename"
    for row in cursor:
            TheStateName1 = row[0]
            thecntyName1 = row[4]
            idpoly1 = row[5]
            idobject1 = row[6]
            stateFIPS1 = row[7]
            countyFIPS1 = row[8]
            fips1 = row[9]
            fipSnum1 = row[10]
            fipsNumer1 = row[11]
            XPoint = row [13]
            YPoint = row[14]

            print TheStateName1
            print thecntyName1

            print row

            Total_X1 +=  row[2] *row[3]
            print Total_X1


            Total_Y1 +=  row[1] *row[3]
            print Total_Y1


            TotalPop1 += row[3]
            print TotalPop1

    print ""        
    print "X is: " , Total_X1
    print "POP is: " , TotalPop1
    centroid_X1 = Total_X1/TotalPop1
    print "your x centroid is: ",centroid_X1
    print ""
    print thecntyName1
    print TheStateName1

########

    print ""        
    print "Y is: " , Total_Y1
    print "POP is: " , TotalPop1
    centroid_Y1 = Total_Y1/TotalPop1
    print "your y centroid is: ",centroid_Y1
    print ""

    cursor01 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutPutCent,["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y","Xcoord","Ycoord","totpop", "NAME","STATE_NAME","POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER" ])

    cursor01.insertRow([XPoint,YPoint,centroid_X1,centroid_Y1,TotalPop1,thecntyName1,TheStateName1,idpoly1, idobject1, stateFIPS1, countyFIPS1, fips1, fipSnum1, fipsNumer1])


print" Done"
```

Comment: Dropping the previous down-voted question and replacing it with a better one is frowned upon, but tolerated.  Yet you still have the same fundamental issue that an MCVE doesn't need any of the code starting with `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` and ending with `######next cursor`.  The `del` is still incorrect.  The UpdateCursor is still inappropriate and placing the InsertCursor inside the loop is still your error.  And you **still** haven't provided any script output. If you expect the volunteers here to debug your code *without* your participation you're likely to be disappointed.

Comment: Are the debug outputs you print showing the correct/expected values? Try running your algorithm with a small dataset and carefully selected features, so you can see what happens.

Comment: There seems to be considerably more code here than is needed to illustrate your problem.  I think you should remove any code that relates to fields that do not participate in your calculation of the weighted centroid, then test that the code snippet illustrates your problem, and then post that code snippet with its output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wild guess is

cursor01 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutPutCent,**["SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"**,"Xcoord","Ycoord","totpop", "NAME","STATE_NAME","POLY_ID", "OBJECTID", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "FIPSnum","FIPS_NUMER" ])

cursor01.insertRow([**XPoint,YPoint**,centroid_X1,centroid_Y1,TotalPop1,thecntyName1,TheStateName1,idpoly1, idobject1, stateFIPS1, countyFIPS1, fips1, fipSnum1, fipsNumer1])

You are inserting the last XPoint and YPoint as SHAPE@x and SHAPE@y. This will, of course, use the last feature.

Use the actual calculated centroid coordinates instead of XPoint and YPoint. That should bring you forward.

Also, what @Vince said.

Comment: The code runs, and it shows the correct centroid, but the attribute table is not updated. It still shows data of the last county.